# Windows driver, spin lock acquisition and condition test

Tags: c++, windows, multithreading, wdm

Inside one dispatch routine we have the following code:

```
if (DeviceExtension->Flag)
{
    KeAcquireInStackQueuedSpinLockAtDpcLevel(&DeviceExtension->SpinLock, &LockHandle);

    //... when we will enter here, DeviceExtension->Flag can already be set to FALSE.

    KeReleaseInStackQueuedSpinLockFromDpcLevel(&LockHandle);
}
```

Inside another dispatch routine we have the following code:

```
KeAcquireInStackQueuedSpinLockAtDpcLevel(&DeviceExtension->SpinLock, &LockHandle);

//...

DeviceExtension->Flag = FALSE;
KeReleaseInStackQueuedSpinLockFromDpcLevel(&LockHandle);
```

So when we will acquire spin lock inside first dispatch routine, `DeviceExtension->Flag` can already be set to `FALSE` by second routine. The solution would be to acquire spin lock and then check `DeviceExtension->Flag`. However `DeviceExtension->Flag` might be FALSE, and spin lock acquisition seems very heavy in this case.

I am not very familiar multithreading, especially in kernel mode. I know that question is stupid, but I got lost. What would be the right solution in this case? Thank you.

Comment: Sounds like you just need [double-checked locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking)? In your first snippet, check the flag again after you lock, and release and abort if false.

Comment: Seems it's functioning "as programmed" the second snippets sets it to `FALSE` and then it stays that way.  The only thing the spin locks are guaranteeing you is "synchronized" access between the calls to `KeAcquireInStackQueuedSpinLockAtDpcLevel` and `KeReleaseInStackQueuedSpinLockFromDpcLevel` perhaps you want to set Flag back to TRUE at the end of the second routine?

Comment: No, actually this flag indicates that device is to be removed, so it works one way.

Comment: @igntec - what you need here - this is exactly [rundown-protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/run-down-protection) instead flag.

Answer (score 1):

> this flag indicates that device is to be removed, so it works one way

for this special exist [Run-Down Protection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/run-down-protection)

you need have `EX_RUNDOWN_REF RunRef;` member in device extension instead `bool Flag`

initialize it with

```
ExInitializeRundownProtection(&RunRef);
```

when you need do some operation, only if device yet not removed you need do:

```
if (ExAcquireRundownProtection(&DeviceExtension->RunRef))
{
    // do something
    ExReleaseRundownProtection(&DeviceExtension->RunRef)
}
```

and in `IRP_MN_REMOVE_DEVICE` handler you need call

```
ExWaitForRundownProtectionRelease(&DeviceExtension->RunRef);
```

---

and important note - despite in msdn stated that `ExAcquireRundownProtection` and `ExReleaseRundownProtection` must be called on `IRQL <= APC_LEVEL` this is false and mistake. `ExAcquireRundownProtection` simply do some interlocked operations with memory to which point `RunRef` - so if it in non-paged pool - we can call this routine at any `IRQL`. device extension is in non-paged pool. the `ExReleaseRundownProtection` can additional call `KeSetEvent` with *Wait* is set to `FALSE`. as result it can be run at `IRQL <= DISPATCH_LEVEL`. `ExReleaseRundownProtection` we typical call from `IoCompletion` routine (which executes at an `IRQL` that is less than or equal to `DISPATCH_LEVEL`) so here all ok.

`ExWaitForRundownProtectionRelease` of course must be called at `<= APC_LEVEL` because here we can wait, but The PnP manager sends `IRP_MN_REMOVE_DEVICE` at `IRQL` `PASSIVE_LEVEL` - so again all ok here

---

of course your here can use and [Remove Locks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/kernel/using-remove-locks) which do almost exactly same as rundown protection. simply rundown-protection - more new api, and much better designed/implemented compare remove locks. however in documentation for `IoReleaseRemoveLock` and `IoReleaseRemoveLock` correctly stated that `IRQL
<= DISPATCH_LEVEL` must be and `IoReleaseRemoveLockAndWait` must be called at `PASSIVE_LEVEL`